# backtick in string to be searched in by powershell

Tags: powershell, string-matching

So, I have an object with this content

```
some text
some more text 
INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES
some text
some more text
```

I want to select the line "INSERT INTO...". Notice the backticks.
When I loop through the content of this particular lineI indeed see that this what is in it: [T][O][ ][`][m][y] ...

Now, when checking the following patterns:

```
$pattern1 = "INSERT INTO *"
$pattern2 = "INSERT INTO `*"
$pattern3 = "INSERT INTO ``*"
$pattern4 = "INSERT INTO `m*"
$pattern5 = 'INSERT INTO `*'
$pattern6 = 'INSERT INTO `r*'

$content | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like $pattern1) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
    if ($_ -like $pattern2) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
    if ($_ -like $pattern3) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
    if ($_ -like $pattern4) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
    if ($_ -like $pattern5) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
    if ($_ -like $pattern6) {
        Write-Output "line '$_' corresponds with pattern"
    } 
}
```

I notice that only pattern 1 and 2 are "triggered" for the right line.
This makes no sence for me.
What am I missing?
Or, more concretely, how can I validate that the entire sequence correcponds with the first line (so I also want to match the backticks )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtick `` ` `` is the [wildcard escaping character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3) of the [`WildcardPattern` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0). If you want to match a literal backtick, the same needs to be escaped:

```bash
'INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES' -like 'INSERT INTO `m*'  # False
'INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES' -like 'INSERT INTO ``m*' # True
```

Note the use of single-quotes in the examples above, this is so the backticks don't expand in the string.

The following should also be an option:

```bash
'INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES' -like "$([WildcardPattern]::Escape('INSERT INTO `m'))*"
```

However, there is an open issue about `WildcardPattern.Escape` not escaping lone backticks properly, please consider upvoting it so we might get this fixed in newer versions of PowerShell. See [GitHub Issue #16306](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16306).

You could use regex matching instead for this particular case:

```bash
'INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES' -match 'INSERT INTO `m.*' # True
```

Comment: Thank you. I "went around" the problem by doing less (but still enough) matching checks, because for my use case, after looking into it, I can do it easier. I did do an upvote for the GitHub issue.